# controller function got undefined

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to set up a AngularJS project using TypeScript but I'm running into the following error:

> Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/areq?p0=MovieCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

I'm also using watchify to compile my app.ts to bundle.js

In my index I bootstrap Angular using `ng-app`, I include a html file (which loads fine) and I import my external files at the bottom of the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-include="'movie.html'"></div>
    <!--Libraries-->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="app/movieCtrl.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

In my `movie.html` I have:

```
<div ng-controller="MovieCtrl as vm"></div>
```

This is the movieCtrl file:

```
class MovieCtrl {

    // fields
    // constructor
    // propperties
    // functions
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Movie',
    MovieCtrl);
```

And finally my app.ts

```
angular.module("app", []);
```

Any ideas why the MovieCtrl is throwing an error?

Comment: Please, move your solution into an answer and accept it.

Comment: You keep answering your own questions; maybe hold off before posting a question?

Comment: And you think that's a good reason to downvote this question? I've searched through multiple questions and non pointend me to the naming convention of the angular module.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 0):

**// ANSWER //**

After reviewing the PluralSight course again (and again) I found the error.

In the movieCtrl file I define the class as `MovieCtrl` but in my module registration I define it as `Movie`. Changing:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Movie',
    MovieCtrl);
```

to

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('MovieCtrl',
    MovieCtrl);
```

Fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

What solve for me, was closing the Controller. Simple, but fix it.

**Just add at the end:**  either  **}**  or  **)**

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function (auth, $scope) { 
  $scope.auth = auth; 
  $scope.$watch('auth.profile.name', function(name) { 
    if (!name) { 
      return;
    } 
    $scope.message.text = 'Welcome ' + auth.profile.name + '!'; 
  });
```

**So the result:**

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function (auth, $scope) { 
  $scope.auth = auth; 
  $scope.$watch('auth.profile.name', function(name) { 
    if (!name) { 
      return;
    } 
    $scope.message.text = 'Welcome ' + auth.profile.name + '!'; 
  });
})
```